# Console Log is not showing anything

Tags: apex, developer-console

I open the Execute Anonymous Window and Execute the following test line:

```
System.debug('Hello');
```

And nothing appears on the Log tab.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you open the debug options and set the timeframe? I have to do it every time I open the dev console as it will not just start logging. Very annoying

Comment: Where are the options Eric?

Comment: Debug -> Change Log Levels

Comment: @Eric, you shouldn't have to. Try deleting all your trace flags, the open the dev console to see if it starts logging for you automatically.

Comment: The Change Log Levels/Expiration has a yellow highligtht "12:NaN PM", I have no idea how to set the timeframe. I am having a hard time to find documentation on this.

Comment: @user1953246 - Um, you pick the expiration time from the drop down list?? Also make sure you click out of the list after selection and into another option as sometimes it will not recognize the change

Comment: @Thomas - I will try delete the trace flags?.  Heck it will not even clear the logs when I tell it to....They just stay there (In the dev console) At lease they keep the sorting now.....

Comment: This might be the most annoying part about developing for SF.  They need to fix this ASAP

Comment: Previously reset option would work fine. Now we have to create a new debug log for that user frequently.

Answer (score 3):

It now works. I do not know exactly what it made it work.

But this is what I did:

1. Deleted trace flags
2. Moved Expiration to an arbitrary value of 4:00 PM
3. Closed the console
4. Opened the console
5. Expiration went back to "12:NaN PM" (still highlighted)

Weird, but it works.