# Delete trace flags

Tags: apex, debugging, console

How can I delete trace flags in Salesforce? My question is in reference to [Console Log is not showing anything](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50493/console-log-is-not-showing-anything).

Answer (score 7):

From developer console, run this query-
"*select id from TraceFlag*"

Select the rows and your trace flags wil be deleted.

Make Sure you check "**Use Tooling API**" before executing the query.

Answer (score 3):

Go To `Setup` -> `Monitoring` -> `Debug Logs`.
This will show you all the user trace flags.

You can also do this via the REST Explorer on workbench.

`/services/data/v35.0/tooling/sobjects/TraceFlag`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Spring '16 version Try to following step:

1. Edit Trace Log and set Time Frame just only change "Start Date" and "End Date".
2. Edit "Filter" and Go to "Apex Code" and set "DEBUG" value.
3. Use System.debug(Logginglevel.Debug,'Hello'); instead of System.debug('Hello');