# How to remove the trace flag in debug log?

Tags: apex, debugging

My sandbox got refreshed. Now I am running some code and want to check the debug log. So I tried to set the trace log but I see so many log created with more user. I see two logs created for some user. I checked the login but they haven't created it.

I don't know what created this all ? now try to remove one by one. Is there any bulk deletion.?

Please suggest.

Comment: why do you care? the debug will have expired for those trace flags; see also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70239/delete-trace-flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this one from tooling API guide and deleted the trace flag.

Open service console. Query

```
select id from TraceFlag
```

Select all rows and click delete button.

Comment: Mark your answer as correct using the Tick icon